# Why is there no layout for a module loaded in my article?

Tags: css, joomla, joomla2.5

So I'm using this extension for my site [RokSprocket](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/articles-showcase/21232?qh=YToxOntpOjA7czoxMToicm9rc3Byb2NrZXQiO30%3D) to show my articles. But my problem is when I load the module inside my article with `{loadposition myposition}` the module appears but with no styling or layout whatsoever like the image below.

[image]

I tried using Modules Anywherebut it's still the same. I tried loaing other modules to my article but it's the same.

Any help?

Comment: Please try to switch to default template to see if it's a template problem.

Comment: I tried using the default atomic template and it was still the same. Here is what i think it should look like http://www.rockettheme.com/docs/joomla/templates/osmosis/demo_module_2.md

Comment: Have you added: `Module Class Suffix: fp-showcase-a rt-center fp-showcase-animate`?

Comment: Yes, I have alreay added that.

Answer (score 0):

As with any type of "module in content" plugin in Joomla, you need to assign the module to a menu item/items in order for it to be displayed